# MySQL - Select from two rows by a shared value where the query values are different

Tags: mysql, sql

Very difficult to phrase this. Let me explain. I have a few tables: teams, games, and team_games. Team_games has a "standing" field which is 0'd by default. If standing is greater than 0, the game is finished and scores have been reported. **I'm trying to come up with a query that will take two team IDs, and count the number of games they have in common where the standing is greater than zero.**

Here's the table. So far I've done everything except for what I want.

```
Teams
---------------------
team_id     team_name
---------------------
   1          Test
   2         Test 2

Games
---------------------
game_id    start_time
---------------------
   1         (unix)
   2           -
   3           -

Team Games
---------------------------------
game_id     team_id      standing
---------------------------------
   1           1             1
   1           2             2
   2           1             2
   2           2             1
   3           1             1
   3           2             2
```

**So again, I want to capture just the rows where team_id is either 1 or 2, and the game id is the same, then count the unique game IDs.**

So if I was looking for the number of games which were finished between team one and team two, the final result would be:

```
-----
COUNT
-----
  3
```

Comment: why is the result `3`?

Comment: It would be counting the number of rows where one row has a sibling row of the same game ID... But the two IDs have to be specified in the query, it can't be just any sibling with the same game ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) totalgames
FROM   
        (
            SELECT  Game_ID
            FROM    TeamGames
            WHERE   team_ID IN (1, 2)   -- specify the teams here
            GROUP   BY Game_ID
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2        -- number of teams specified
                    AND SUM(standing = 0) = 0
        ) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01a45/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╗
║ TOTALGAMES ║
╠════════════╣
║          3 ║
╚════════════╝
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you so much - I'm also very impressed that you understood what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but this may work
`select count(distinct game_id) as games_number from Team_Games where (team_id = 1 or team_id = 2) and standing >= 1;`

Comment: This would fail if there were a set of team_games which had the same game_id but one had team_id = 3 while the other had team_id = 2

Comment: you'are right. i just supposed that game_id can be only twice. i don't know about what sport is that DB but if in one game can participate only two teams i would make Team_Game with team_id_1 and team_id_2 and make the game_id unique.

Comment: This is true in most cases, yes. In fact, I'll have to consider the reality of having more than two teams - because it turns this whole process into a nightmare. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove team from select clause and as well as group by, if you want.

```
SELECT T1.TEAM_ID, T2.TEAM_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM
TEAM_GAMES T1, TEAM_GAMES T2
WHERE T2.TEAM_ID <> T1.TEAM_ID
AND T2.GAME_ID = T2.GAME_ID
AND T1.STANDING > 0 AND T2.STANDING > 0
GROUP BY T1.TEAM_ID, T2.TEAM_ID
```